# passing List<String> to method expecting List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

In `Page 112 of CHAPTER 5 GENERICS in the book - Effective Java` , these sentences appears

> Just what is the difference between the raw type `List` and the
>   parameterized type `List<Object>` ...While you can pass a `List<String>`
>   to a parameter of type List, you can’t pass it to a parameter of type
>   `List<Object>`

I tried this

```
public static void getMeListOfObjs(List<Object> al){
    System.out.println(al.get(0));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();

    String mys1 = "jon";

    al.add(mys1);

    getMeListOfObjs(al);


}
```

It runs without any error... Was that an error in book content? I am quoting from the second edition

Comment: you declared al as List<Object>

Comment: There's no `List<String>` anywhere in your program.

Comment: Change `List<Object> al` by `List<String> al`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void getMeListOfObjs(List<? extends Object> al) {
    System.out.println(al.get(0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    String mys1 = "jon";

    al.add(mys1);

    getMeListOfObjs(al);


}
```

This wont compile, because `List<String>` isn't match `List<Object>`

As @darijan pointed out the wildcard ? extends the type chack with all class that is descendant of it.

I recommend to read more about [generics and wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

Comment: it would be great if you can also explain why the code is running successfully

Comment: sorry..this was what I was trying to do..didn't catch that that typo

Comment: @damon then can you correct typo in your question, please

Comment: It does compile

Answer (score 4):

The code you provided works. I guess you want your `al` list to be `List<String>`. Then, you would have to make `getMeListOfObjs` like this:

```
public static void getMeListOfObjs(List<? extends Object> al) {
    System.out.println(al.get(0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String mys1 = "jon";
    al.add(mys1);
    getMeListOfObjs(al);
}
```

Notice the difference?

```
public static void getMeListOfObjs(List<? extends Object> al) {
```

The wildcard `?` changes any type that extends `Object`, i.e. any object.

Answer (score 1):

The example you have created does not create a `List<String>`. You also use a `List<Object>` you just add Strings to the Object list. So you essentially pass Object list, that's why it works.  You can add any object the the object list including string. It works since the String extends  Object.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `List<Object>` only. If your concern is that you have passed a `String` in the `List<Object>` that is perfectly fine because `String` IS-A `Object`.

Because even if you are putting a `String` as an element in the `List<Object>`, you are passing a `List<Object>` to the method.

Answer (score 0):

The book is saying that you can do this:

```
List al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(but Eclipse suggest you not to use raw types... "List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized")

but you can't do this:

```
List<Object> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

because the compiler recognizes a type mismatch "cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to List<Object>"